# How to find the common letters for two words?

Tags: string, swift, cocoa-touch

I am coding a simple love calculator in swift.  The way it works is it takes two people's names and adds the number of letters together. Then it finds the number of letters in common, subtracts it from the total, and divides that number by the total to get the percentage of chance. For example:

- Person 1: Charles
- Person 2: Jane
- Charles + Jane = 11 letters total
- Charles and Jane have an A and an E in common, so subtract the two E's and two A's from 11, we get 7. 7 divided by 11 is 63%.

**My question is what is the best way to find the letters in common?**

I am fairly new to swift, but I have worked with objective C before. Here is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Love Calculator
//
//  Created by Caden Farley on 8/18/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Caden Farley. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var total = 0
    @IBOutlet var person1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var person2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var resultText: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed () {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        let string1 = person1.text
        let string2 = person2.text

        total = count(string1) + count(string1)
        resultText.text = "\(total)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's duplicates for this question and they are useful, but they're all using Foundation methods.

Here's a simple way to find the common letters for two words in pure Swift 2.0 using `Set`:

```
let person1 = "Charles"
let person2 = "Jane"

let p1Set = Set(person1.lowercaseString.characters)
let p2Set = Set(person2.lowercaseString.characters)

let common = Array(p1Set.intersect(p2Set)).map({ String($0) })

print(common.count)  // 2

for letter in common {
    print(letter)  // "e", "a"
}
```

Only slightly different in Swift 1.2:

```
let person1 = "Charles"
let person2 = "Jane"

let p1Set = Set(person1.lowercaseString)
let p2Set = Set(person2.lowercaseString)

let common = Array(p1Set.intersect(p2Set)).map({ String($0) })

println(common.count)  // 2

for letter in common {
    println(letter)  // "e", "a"
}
```

Of course, using `Set` means that it counts only the unique letters, not the number of occurrences.

For that you would have to use something like `NSCountedSet` (but there's already examples for that on SO).

Answer (score 0):

```
func compatability(a: String, _ b: String) -> Int {
  let (aC, bC) = (a.lowercaseString.characters, b.lowercaseString.characters)
  let matches = { (col: String.CharacterView, set: Set<Character>) in
    col.reduce(0) { (sum, c) in set.contains(c) ? sum + 1 : sum }
  }
  let tot = aC.count + bC.count
  let com = matches(aC, Set(bC)) + matches(bC, Set(aC))
  return (tot - com) * 100 / tot
}

compatability("Charles", "Jane") // 63
```